# Dynamic JSON Object using responce entity - Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using return ResponseEntity of Spring to return HTTP response.

While passing POJO or MAP in entity, it converts that to JSON Object. Like

```
  return new ResponseEntity<Object>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
```

result may be POJO class. (getter and setters)

I am using

```
 <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter ">
</bean>
```

Now what i want is, i will get a list of response fields in request. I just want to response the request with those fields only.

For Ex, if i receive the response fields as name,id. Then the object must contain those two only.

```
 {
 "name":"test",
 "id":15
 }
```

i can't able to use @jsonignore or @explore annotations. B'Coz i want the JSON to be done dynamically using coding.

May be by overriding the GSON convertor methods or using AOP.

Is there any way to configure the adapter of jackson to create the object based on the fields.

Comment: You mean you want to sent response that is a object containing what values you have received in request correct ? Is number of request values is fixed or dynamic ?

Comment: s exactly. what are all the fields in the request need to be sent as object (POJO already have those fields. But lot other than that. we need to exclude). It is dynamic. We don't know what will come.

Comment: Do you need to use Gson or can you switch to Jackson?

Comment: Ya no problem. may use jackson as well. Is there any way to do in jackson. Actually, first i used jackson only. For this only i shifted to GSON.

Comment: Is POJO class created dynamically? Or you just want to ignore null values?

Comment: Not null vales. Just want to exclude the fields not in the response string, which i get through request. If POJO having 2 fields like name and ID, i am getting only name in the response field, then object have to create with that name only. no ID needed irrespective of its value.

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch to jackson probably you can use this little extension i wrote for exactly this purpose:

https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter

Comment: Thanks martin. As per your examples in github, i have to add objectmapper in every method, which works after conversion . I there anyway to tell jackson before converting.

Comment: I did create a spring bean encapsulating the neccessary code with a helper method. `bean.write(obj, "filters",...)`. I did not yet try to incorporate it with responsebody. My controllers return a string directly.

Comment: The `mixin` configuration can be done only once as it works on `Object`. In the `@PostConstruct` of the spring bean for example.

Comment: Ok. What about objectmapper. Can we configure that to achieve this.

Comment: I think i will add an example on the github readme. Give me some time ;)

Comment: @user1677237 I have added an example for Spring Integration into the readme. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I have now incorporated the `Jackson2Helper` into the project to simplify usage and integration with Spring.